# What is the best way to make a singly linked list of integer digits in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am having trouble with producing a singly linked list in Python of the digits of an integer backwards. The output I'm getting makes absolutely no sense.

The integer is as follows:

`1000000000000000000000000000466`

The output should be:

`[6,6,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`

But instead, it is:

`[6,6,2,2,4,4,2,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`

The code snippet is below:

*sum3 is the integer I'm trying to convert to a list

*counter3 is the number of digits

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next

        ret = ListNode( sum3%(10) )
        sum3 = int(sum3/10)
        temp=ret
        for i in range(1,counter3):
            temp.next = ListNode(sum3%(10)) 
            temp = temp.next
            sum3 = int(sum3/10)

        return ret
```

Comment: counter3 is the number of digits right?

Comment: @vbhargav875 Yes!

Comment: This is why you're supposed to use `//` instead of `/` and rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is extract the digits from the integer.  Converting it to a string is the solution here because then you'll be able to iterate over the characters.

For example,

```
for c in str(12345):
    print(c)
```

outputs

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Of course, that will produce characters for you but you can easily convert them back to integers.

You also want your digits ordered from the least significant to the most.  Therefore, you'll need to reverse the list.

So,

```
ret = [int(c) for c in str(sum3)][::-1]
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand why it addresses the problem. That often reduces the amount of follow-up questions, and can really help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Comment: Got it, thanks! But why does the current output differ from the integer?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  It looks to be some sort of rounding issue.  For example, `print(int(1000000000000000000000000000466/10))` gives 99999999999999991433150857216.

Comment: In Python 3, you should use the `//` operator to do integer division.  `1000000000000000000000000000466 // 10` correctly returns 100000000000000000000000000046.